# print the calendar created with fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I have the following calendar where I want to print the listMonth. I am organizing my code as follows:

```js
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0});
  if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        initialViews = 'listMonth';
        
   }else{
        initialViews = 'listMonth';

   }  

    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendarioo');
    var today = moment().day();

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        headerToolbar: {
            left: false,
            center: 'title',
            right: false
        },
        locale: "pt-br",

        navLinks: true,             
        initialView: initialViews,
        eventColor: '#f16621', 

        eventContent: function(info) {

                
          return { html: '<div class="ui top label grey attached"><strong>Utente:</strong> ' + info.event.title + '</div><br><div class="ui top label grey attached"><strong>Responsável:</strong> ' + info.event.extendedProps.respons + '</div><br><div class="ui top label grey attached"><strong>Local da Visita:</strong> ' + info.event.extendedProps.Localvisita + '</div>' };
        },

        events: [
        { id: '1', title: 'teste', respons: 'testeee', contact: '000000001', start: '2023-10-26T10:00:00', end: '2023-10-26T13:18:00' },
        { id: '2', title: 'teste1', respons: 'testeee1', contact: '000000002', start: '2023-10-27T10:00:00', end: '2023-10-27T13:18:00' },
        { id: '3', title: 'teste2', respons: 'testeee2', contact: '000000003', start: '2023-10-28T10:00:00', end: '2023-10-28T13:18:00' },
        { id: '4', title: 'teste2', respons: 'testeee2', contact: '000000003', start: '2023-10-29T10:00:00', end: '2023-10-29T13:18:00' },
        { id: '5', title: 'teste2', respons: 'testeee2', contact: '000000003', start: '2023-10-30T10:00:00', end: '2023-10-30T13:18:00' },
        { id: '6', title: 'teste2', respons: 'testeee2', contact: '000000003', start: '2023-10-31T10:00:00', end: '2023-10-31T13:18:00' }
      ],
        
    });
    calendar.render();
    
document.getElementById("btnPrintvisit").onclick = function () {
    printElement(document.getElementById("printThvisit")); 
}

function printElement(elem) {

    var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);
    
    var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");
    
    if (!$printSection) {
        var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
        $printSection.id = "printSection";
        document.body.appendChild($printSection);
    }
    console.log($printSection);
    $printSection.innerHTML = "";
    $printSection.appendChild(domClone);
    window.print();

}
```

```css
@media screen {
    #printSection {
        display: none !important;
    }
}

@media print {
    #printSection, #printSection * {
      visibility:visible !important;
    }
    #printSection {
      position: relative;
      left:0 !important;
      top:0 !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.9.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.9.0/main.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item" id="btnPrintvisit">Print</button>

<div id="printThvisit"><div id='calendarioo'></div></div>
```

After creating the example I will explain my two problems:

The first is that you can't duplicate the same information twice.

The second problem is that as the list has a scrollbar, what is inside this scrollbar does not appear in the printout. I wanted all the information to appear when printing.

It only prints what appears on the screen and should print all the information returned in the calendar

Can anyone help overcome this problem?

Comment: fullcalendar already comes with its own print CSS, I don't think you really need to add your own. Try without your extra CSS. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/full/qBbMJRv